# How to pass the facebook response object to php object?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-apps

When the user successes to login facebook, there is a response object in the javascript. How can I pass this object to PHP by using post or other methods?

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId: '12345788', // App ID
                channelUrl: /channel.html', // Channel File
                status: true, // check login status
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
            });

            // Additional init code here
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    // connected
                    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                    // not_authorized


                } else {
                    // not_logged_in

                }

            });
```

Comment: What do you mean by *php object*? Normal `stdClass` object?

Comment: `for(i in object) {...}`

Comment: I believe he means associative array.